# Information gain or regression for measuring to what extent a continuous quantity detemines a discrete one?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, information-theory

I have a small population S and two quantities P and Q associated to its members. P is integer valued (say, age taking integer values between 1 and 20) and Q real valued (say, height in meters). I can measure them for the whole population S. I want to see to what extent Q determines P. I think [information gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio) is a good measure for this, better than regression, but am not sure.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  This post may be a little too abstract to be answerable.  Could you say more about what $Q$ and $P$ represent? Could $P$ be ordinal?  How many possible values might it have? Is it accurately measured or known?  How to you sample the population?

Comment: Hi, I did so and clarified.